# Error while loading dll in Docker Container although it exists in it

Tags: c#, .net, docker, apache-kafka, windows-container

I'm trying to run a .Net 4.72 app on Docker. That app executed perfectly on my computer, but when I run it on a Docker container, I receive `error while loading librdkafka.dll or its dependencies from C:\temp\source\bin\x64\Debug\librdkafka\x64\librdkafka.dll. Check the directory exists, if not check your deployment process. You can also load the library and its dependencies by yourself before any call to Confluent.Kafka`.

I verified it's there using a dir command on that folder
[image: verification of librdkafka.dll]

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
WORKDIR /source

COPY "./bin/x64/Debug/." "c:/temp/source/bin/x64/Debug/"

RUN powershell.exe dir c:/temp/source/bin/x64/Debug/librdkafka/x64

CMD ["c:/temp/source/bin/x64/Debug/testeh.exe"]
```

Comment: And are you sure you have all the dependencies librdkafka needs? Something like the correct version of VC++ Runtime comes to my mind here that might be missing on a clean server core machine. But on your development machine where you presumably tried it it will be definitely in your path.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf , it works after installing the VC Runtime

ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after installing the VC++ Runtime

```
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install
```